# How to filter and recognise hash strings in PHP?

Tags: php, security, hash, sha1

At the beginning of every php script, I loop through the possible `POST` and `GET` inputs, filter them properly, so later when I need an input, I can use my custom, safe, filtered  variable, (which is an array, that holds POSTS and GETS) and I do not have to touch $_GET and $_POST.

If the variable is a hash-value, either a 40 character SHA1, or a 64 character Adobe Stratus ID, how do I recognise them?

I do not want the user, to post some nonsense data.

Comment: You want to make sure a variable contains either a 40 or 60 characters long alphanumeric string?

Comment: What characters are allowed in an Adobe Stratus ID? By the way, Stratus is now called Cirrus.

Comment: For SHA1, you should check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982059/testing-if-string-is-sha1-in-php

Comment: How do you actually filter them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test whether a string is a x length hash value or not:

```
$x = 40
$string = "inputstring";
$boolResult = (preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{'$x'}$/i', $string) == true) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree that you should avoid _POST and _GET access, but instead you should clean them where possible to avoid XSS. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). CodeIgniter has a great security library you can pinch and plug into your own stuff.

Other than that, I'm not sure... but I think you are asking to decrypt hashed values from the session?

Comment: Not possible to decrypt. All I want is a Boolean that tels me if a string is a hash or not.

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089428/possible-to-identify-hash-type

Answer (score 0):

When most of the hash `sha` , `md5` etc returns hex format .. you can easily detect them using `ctype_xdigit`

```
if (ctype_xdigit($value)) {
    // It must be Hex
}
```

I don't know what `Adobe Stratus ID` looks like but you can easily validated that with `preg_match` too.

Some can also come in `base64` you can also validated that with

```
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
   // it must be base 64
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can match a SHA1 hash with a regex like :

```
/[0-9a-f]{40}/
```

in PHP :

```
foreach($_GET as $get) {
    if (preg_match('/[0-9a-f]{40}/i', $get)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```